# the script does not run via crontab

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, system-administration, oraclelinux

That my python script:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(
'REPOR',
'REPOR',
'192.168.10.50:1521/db',
encoding='UTF-8'
) 
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    command = "df -h / /u01"
    result = subprocess.check_output(command, 
shell=True).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
    row = [('dm01dbadm01', result, datetime.now(), '0')]
    cursor.bindarraysize = 1
    cursor.executemany("insert into HISTORY values (:1, :2, :3, :4)", row)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("Ok!")
except:
    print("Oooops! Error!"
```

this script writes the result of this df -h command to the database.

Runs perfectly fine in linux terminal

From terminal i m excecuting the script with following commands:
`export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1 scl enable python27 -- python2.7 /u01/app/Scripts/script.py`

To run from crontab i did the following:

Created bash script with following entries:
`export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1 scl enable python27 -- python2.7 /u01/app/Scripts/script.py`

After cron is excecuting the script, but it shows Oooops! Error!.
So, why the script is not excecuting from crontab as well?

Comment: Cron jobs run with a limited environment. Educated guess: `df` is not found in `PATH`, therefore the script crashes. Why don't you print the exception details when you catch it? Having more than just "error" (or "oops") helps immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you import the crx_Oracle and subprocess modules first?

Also refer to the "scl" tool by its path.

A crontab script does not get the full initialization that a login shell gets.  Check the crontab documentation to get an exact description of the runtime environment that your script must run within.